# How to add win32com.client as a dependency in requirements.txt for a docker image?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, pywin32

I am building a container with python script that sends an email using outlook. I am having trouble adding win32com to my container in the build process. It gives the error `No module named 'win32com'`. Can someone please help I can't find a solution online. Here's my code:

email.py

```
import win32com.client as win32
# import json
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI() 


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'bilalhussain.v1@gmail.com'
    mail.Subject = 'Testing Email Through Outlook'
    mail.Body = 'This shouldnot have taken this long'
    mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>Hello World</h2>' #this field is optional

        # To attach a file to the email (optional):
    attachment  = "find.json"
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

    mail.Send()
```

requirements.txt

```
certifi==2020.12.5
click==7.1.2
fastapi==0.63.0
h11==0.11.0
starlette==0.13.6
uvicorn==0.13.3
pywin32==304
win32-setctime==1.0.3
win32com 
pypiwin32
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

ADD find.json .
ADD email.py .

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the closest you can get is installing wine inside the container and executing your code under wine.

You will need to install python with wine prior.

There are [wine ready docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/scottyhardy/docker-wine/#!).

In any case I do not think it is going to work for your purpose, Outlook if exists in the container will not be properly configured.

Comment: What approach should I take to build a container with code that sends emails if not outlook? Does using smtp with gmail help?